# Need to boot from USB on laptop that doesn't support booting from USB devices

Tags: boot, bios

MY Sony Vaio VGN FS93G laptop doesn't support booting from USB in the BIOS. Normally I can boot the laptop from the built-in DVD-ROM drive but the drive doesn't work and I can't afford a new one right now.

Therefore I'm trying to boot the laptop from a USB DVD-ROM drive, but it's not detected in the boot  screen.

Please kindly suggest solutions for this problem.

Comment: Sure there is no "Boot from external device" option in your BIOS? Updated BIOS to the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Boot from USB without BIOS Support; In the following tutorial, we explain how to create a PLoP Boot Manager CD that can be used to boot from your USB Flash Drive. This is useful for computer systems that do not support booting from USB in BIOS.  The PLoP Boot Manager created by Elmar Hanlhofer, works by first loading essential USB drivers,  CD/DVD drivers, and Hard Disk Drivers. The user is then presented with a (Boot Menu) menu of possible boot devices detected by PLoP. The user can then proceed to select a device to try and boot from.

PLoP Boot Manager (Boot Menu)

PLoP Boot Manager

Distribution Home Page: PLoP Boot Manager

How to Create a PLoP Boot Manager CD

Download PLoP Boot manager, and extract the files from the Zip to your Desktop
Burn the plpbt.iso to a CD using your favorite CD/DVD burning software
Insert your Newly created PLoP Boot CD and your  pre-prepared Linux USB Flash Drive
Reboot your PC and set your System BIOS to boot from the CD
If all goes as planned, you should now be presented with an alternate Boot Manager similar to the one pictured above that can be used to boot your USB Flash Drive or other device.

Note: In some cases the Flash Drive will actually appear as a hard disk.

Visit: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-from-usb-without-bios-support-via-plop-cd/

Comment: You need to provide quotes, otherwise, anything not in quotes we assume you wrote which you didn't in this case.  You provide a link but improperly quote the material.