# How to install OS to an old laptop - can I install an OS into a Laptop HDD directly?

Tags: linux

I have an old Compaq Presario v2000 that doesn't have an OS, working DVD or USB booting. Well, the link in the first comment says this might be possible however that is not yet tried out.

It does have a working `grub` though none of the OS really boots up. It was working until I tried to resize the primary parition when it was mounted.

My goal is to to install an OS into the HDD without the last possible option ie PXE Boot.

Is there any fancy things I could do at the grub level to make things work again? If not, would it possible to use a IDE-HDD USB and `dd` an ISO into this or installing a complete OS from a different machine? I am just hacking around to learn mostly. Any other novel approaches are also welcome!

Some related links:

[Need to boot from USB on laptop that doesn't support booting from USB devices](https://superuser.com/questions/818617/need-to-boot-from-usb-on-laptop-that-doesnt-support-booting-from-usb-devices)

[Booting from USB when BIOS doesn't support it?](https://superuser.com/questions/47038/booting-from-usb-when-bios-doesnt-support-it)

Comment: This link is pretty good https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/installing-linux-lite/(solved)-installing-on-an-old-laptop/

Answer (score 1):

OK, once I did copies of a HDD with Windows 7 to two totally different PC's with Acronis True Image software.  Quite a burden, i.e. first finding the different chipset drivers to be replacing the source OS's drivers during the copy process, but, anyway, got two more well working 99% cloned copies ready for use instantly.  What then happened with the Windows 7 activations, I do not anymore remember ...

Comment: Getting it work with Windows 7 would mean Linux would be easier usually. And dd is the default image software in Linux. All my hope is in dd command :)