# Can I install Linux from the same HDD?

Tags: linux, installation

Would it be possible for me to burn a Bootable ISO to a HDD connected via USB? I then need to connect this HDD to an old laptop (Compaq Presario v2000), boot from this ISO and install OS into this HDD itself possibly replacing the existing ISO or to another parition on this HDD. But then how do I actually setup so that I can have a a bootable ISO in one and installation on another?

Basically I am trying to solve:
[How to install OS to an old laptop - can I install an OS into a Laptop HDD directly?](https://superuser.com/questions/1113365/how-to-install-os-to-an-old-laptop-can-i-install-an-os-into-a-laptop-hdd-direc/1113376#1113376)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible, I would just install Linux onto the HDD.  You may need to install the generic image from a USB drive, although I would expect you should have no significant issues with command line access from any image.  You may have video issues, but those should resolve if your update the boot image.

To install using an ISO image from the HDD, I would install the ISO image into a partition intended as a swap partition using a USB installer.  When you are done the installation, add the partition as a swap partition.

Comment: Do you mean I take the HDD out partition it with ext4, set the boot flag,  install OS into it and put it back?

Comment: @Nishant  Yes, that should work.